# send Email with Attachment as csv file

Tags: android

i am trying to send attachment in email as csv file from emulator. Email is sent but there is no attachment. also it gives me a toast message "file to large to attach"

public class MainActivityActivity extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String dir = "/Android/data/com.pucit/csv/";
    String fullDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + dir;
    generateCsvFile(fullDir, "data.csv");

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"data.csv"));
    Log.d("321", "a"+uri.toString());


    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"ninja9196@gmail.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/data.csv"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "gmail.com");

    MainActivityActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

}

private static void generateCsvFile(String dir, String fileName) {
    try {

        File theDir = new File(dir);
        theDir.mkdirs();

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(dir + fileName);

        writer.append("DisplayName");

        //generate whatever data you want

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("file", e.getMessage());
    }     
}
```

}

Comment: "file too large to attach" I think that explains itself.

Comment: Aaaand, how large is `data.csv`?

Comment: i m writing in it just" Display Name". its size is 16.

Comment: You're adding in your `dir` variable to the path when you generate the CSV, but not when you attach it. You're looking at a different file.

Comment: Thanks kabuko... it is working now.